# Are vectors written using square or round brackets?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors

Are vectors commonly written as

$$\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$$

or

$$\vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$$

I've learned in school that one should always use round brackets and this is what I usually (if not always) see on the internet or in books. However, in [this 3blue1brown series](https://youtu.be/fNk_zzaMoSs), it is said that vectors are written with square brackets.

This got me wondering whether there is any "official" convention or if there are any reasons why one should be used over the other. If not, which of these is most commonly used?

Note: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I am primarily talking about vectors in linear algebra (which is, as far as I know, anyway the field where vectors are most commonly used), but if it differs, an insight into the notation of vectors in other fields also seems interesting.

Comment: I think both are acceptable.

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: Notation mutates over the years. Authorized one year, official the next, then deprecated, and finally forbidden.

Comment: If vertical composition is not available you can even use the transposition notation $\vec v=(a,b,c)^T$, in that case parenthesis are much more common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learnt the notation as round brackets, and I would suspect (don't **quote** me on this) - most people also learnt with round brackets. However, it does not matter in the grand scheme of things. Ultimately you can use any notation you want (unless you are trying to do some exam or homework or something, don't do this, as it'll make it harder for the instructor to mark and they may give you $0$ because of this). Symbols only have the meaning we give them. If I wanted to be really crazy, I could swap the symbols $1$ and $2$ around, so now $2$ is the smallest positive integer, and ${2+2=1}$ (that was really hard to type).